# How to display current User data from firebase?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, user-controls

I want to display My user name, phone number, etc. in the user profile when the user is logged in from firebase firestore.
I have Firebase firestore Database and the collection name of firestore is **'users'**.

In my project, I want to display current user information like name, email, Number, but I can't do it.

When I run my app the name show blank.

here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gtu_all_in_one/Pages/FirstPage.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../Providers/SignInProvider.dart';
import '../Utils/NextScreen.dart';

import '../models/QrCodeScannerPage.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  String? name = " ";
  String? email;

  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future _getDataFromDatabase() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) async {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          name = snapshot.data()!["name"];
          email = snapshot.data()!["Email"];
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getDataFromDatabase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // for show data on screen
    final sp = context.watch<SignInProvider>();

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 300),

              //here i display name of current user
              Text("Name is : $name"),

              SizedBox(height: 10),

              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 70,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("name is :" + name.toString());
                  },
                  child: Text("Btn"),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 10),

              //for Opening QR Code Scanner
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 250,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: HexColor("#48EDC5"),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                    ),
                  ),

                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      //for text
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13),
                        child: Text(
                          "Mark Attendance",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Gotham',
                              color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //for Icone
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.qr_code_scanner,
                          size: 22,
                          color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //goto QR Code Scanner Page
                  onPressed: () {
                    nextScreen(context, QRCodeScanner());
                  },
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 10),

              //for LogOut Button
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 150,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: HexColor("#48EDC5"),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                    ),
                  ),

                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      //for text
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13),
                        child: Text(
                          "log Out",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Gotham',
                              color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),

                      //for Icone
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                          size: 22,
                          color: HexColor("#002C00"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //goto SignUp Page
                  onPressed: () {
                    sp.userSignOut();
                    nextScreenReplace(context, FirstPage());
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my O/P
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5muLI.jpg)

Comment: try to print your variables in the then code block to know if they exist or not !

Comment: @Gwhyyyi try it but nothing is print

Comment: then you should double check you firestore get() call, make sure you didn't miss a letter, space, underscore in the collection name, and try to print the user uid in the debug log and compare it with the document's name in your collection

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamBuilder(
stream:
  Firestore.instance.collection('userData').snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
 }
 return Container(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 75.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          snapshot.data.documents[0]['userName'],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child:
              Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['email']),
        ),
        ],
       ),
     ),
    );
    }),
```